# How to break out of the foreach loop at first result and continue loop from the 2nd result

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, break, laravel-5.8

I have added this `foreach` for printing gallery images. But I don't want to print the gallery thumbnail inside the gallery images.

So I tried counting all the available images and initializing another variable `$i=0`. So if `$i == 0`, it means that the first image is thumbnail so it should break out of the foreach loop and restarts the loop to print the 2nd image.

Here is the code:

```
@php
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($gallery->galleryImages->where( 'gli_dimension', 'fullsize' ));
@endphp
@foreach( $gallery->galleryImages->where( 'gli_dimension', 'fullsize' ) as $img )
    @if ($i == 0)
        @php
           $i++;
           break;
        @endphp
    @endif
    <div style="display: none;">
        <a href="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url( $img['gli_path']) }}"
            data-fancybox="images-preview{{$gallery->gly_id}}"
            data-width="1500" data-height="1000"
            data-thumb="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url( $img['gli_path'] ) }}"
            data-caption="{{ $gallery->gly_title }}"></a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

But now the problem is, it prints out the thumbnail and not the gallery images at all.

However, it was supposed to print all the gallery images, except the thumbnail.

So how to break out of the foreach loop at the first result and continue the loop from the 2nd result properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[laravel provides loop variables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable)

Also when you use break it will jump out of a loop. So use continue instead of break

[break and continue](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_break.asp)

```
      @php
          $i = 0;
          $len = count($gallery->galleryImages->where( 'gli_dimension', 'fullsize' ));
      @endphp
      @foreach( $gallery->galleryImages->where( 'gli_dimension', 'fullsize' ) as $img )
          @if ($loop->first)
              @php
                 $i++;
                 continue;
              @endphp
          @endif
          <div style="display: none;">
              <a href="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url( $img['gli_path']) }}"
                  data-fancybox="images-preview{{$gallery->gly_id}}"
        data-width="1500" data-height="1000"
        data-thumb="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url( $img['gli_path'] ) }}"
                  data-caption="{{ $gallery->gly_title }}"></a>
          </div>
      @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution for you.
Separate the thumbnail image and gallery images in the database with the new column 'image_type', set the value to 0 where images that are thumbnail, and set the value to 1 where images are all other gallery images.
So you can easily get all the gallery images by applying the condition in the sql query like 'select * from table where image_type = 1'